# Wget resume algorithm

Tags: algorithm, wget, resume

I've noticed that resuming an interrupted download with `wget -c` is very fast and very reliable.

Does `wget` use any algorithm to resume the download, or does it simply compare sizes and appends to the existing file?

Comment: It resume download from size of file on your disk. Downloaded data just appends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this answer help ?

http://www.ale.org/pipermail/ale/2005-November/082061.html

> Wget looks at the file size and assumes retrieval should continue with
>   the next byte past the end of the downloaded file segment.   Wget then
>   sends an http 'range' header field to the server to tell it where to
>   restart the retrieval.

Comment: It means that there are no rsync-style checksums done. Thanks!